# Rename "rows" in findAndCountAll Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Is it possible to have a different key for `result.row` when using `findAndCountAll` in **Sequelize**?

I'm using `findAndCountAll` for **pagination**. I get this structure of data:

```
{
    "count": 8,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "brands",
            "color": "#D83660",
            "createdAt": "2020-05-12T13:51:47.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-12T13:51:47.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to rename the "rows" to something else. How do I do it?
I couldn't find it in the doc. https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAndCountAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, fork Sequelize, and change the function so that it returns the new name you want, or if you just want to change the name because you're passing the result somewhere else, as Salesh mentioned, you can do the following:

```
let result = await MyModel.findAndCountAll()
result.newName = result.rows
delete result.rows
```

EDIT: alternatively, you might wanna copy them into a whole new object, the returned Sequelize objects usually have extra methods you might not want to invoke accidentally later on, so you'd do

```
let data = {
   count: result.count,
   newName: result.rows
}
```

note: that applies to the objects inside the rows array too.

Comment: AWESOME! Works great!!! While Salesh gave a nice answer too, yours have a sample code, which is helpful for newbies like me in js. Now I know that I can just customize the keys of the objects by well... creating a new object. :).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with Sequelize.
As you saw in the documentation.

```
public static async findAndCountAll(options: object): Promise<{count: number, rows: Model[]}>
```

This is basically how this function in the library is returning and there are no options to change that.
Thes best you can is to assign result.rows and pack after in .then function or if you use asyc/await after you get it.

This is possible in MongoDB but here we don't have a projections.